# Return an NSDictionary from another Class When Button is Clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a question about passing data in iOS/Objective-C. I just started creating an app that connects and fetches data from a website, and now I'm having a problem.

My default and root view controller is called `ViewController`. It has the basic login UI views: 2 textfields and a button.

When the button has been clicked/touched, the `ViewController` calls a method from another class called `LoginService`. Now `LoginService` handles the connection to the website. I have no problem connecting to the website and fetching data from it, but I have a problem returning the fetched data, now processed as an NSDictionary, to the `ViewController`.

The first thing I tried was to create a setter method in the `ViewController` that sets the instance variable `userProfile` to the NSDictionary passed into it. It failed, however. I tried using it in the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate method `connectionDidFinishLoading` from the `LoginService`.

This might be a silly question, but I have no idea how can I pass the fetched NSDictionary from LoginService to the ViewController after the button is clicked. Do I need blocks, queue, or something else? I mean, for example, I need to set a label below my login button to the name of the user who logged in. How can I perform this?

Hope someone can help me. I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You basically need to understand the "delegate" pattern which is often used for these kinds of purposes. Read up on it here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm


Alternatively you could implement a solution using blocks: http://www.abdus.me/ios-programming-tips/uialertview-with-blocks-call-back/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As danh has explained blocks pattern for doing this, I will try to explain the delegating pattern. The steps for making this work:

In `LoginService.h`

Create a protocol definition in your LoginService like this:

```
    @protocol LoginServiceDelegate

    -(void)applicationLoggedIn:(NSMutableDictionary*) responseData;

    @end
```

Now add a member pointer holding this delegate and add a property for this

```
    @interface LoginService {

        id<LoginServiceDelegate>delegate;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, assign) id <LoginServiceDelegate> delegate;
```

In `LoginService.m`

Once you got the response for login in `connectionDidFinishLoading`, just invoke the delegate method like below:

```
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationLoggedIn:)]) {
            [delegate applicationLoggedIn:responseDict];
    }
```

In `LoginViewController.h`

Now to use this in your `LoginViewController`, you need to implement this protocol

```
    #import "LoginService.h"
    @interface LoginViewController<LoginServiceDelegate>
```

In `LoginViewController.m`

Assign the delegate of LoginService to LoginViewController

```
    LoginService* loginService = [[LoginService alloc]init];
    loginService.delegate = self;
```

Implement the protocol method as:

```
    -(void)applicationLoggedIn:(NSDictionary*)response{

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I have a question. This, to me, seems to be a the correct way to do what I wanted to do. I just wanna ask why do I have to use this piece of codes: `if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationLoggedIn:)]) {
            [delegate applicationLoggedIn:responseDict];
    }` hope to hear from you, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need ViewController to have a public method which LoginService can call when it's done its job, and NSDictionary will be a parameter to this method. LoginService will need a reference back to ViewController in order to invoke this method, so define a public property on LoginService which will hold a ViewController reference - and set this right after instantiating LoginService.

Of course, if you want LoginService to be more reusable, and not tied to ViewController specifically, delegates are the way to go. LoginService would define the LoginServiceDelegate protocol with the method to be called on completion. ViewController would then implement the LoginServiceDelegate protocol. The public property on LoginService becomes a LoginServiceDelegate reference, and so LoginService no longer needs to import ViewController. This way, ViewController is dependent on LoginService, but LoginService is not dependent on ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Two patterns to consider: delegate and block.  Block is quicker to code, and I usually prefer it to delegate for network ops.  To use a block, write the login service this way:

```
// LoginService.h

- (void)login:(NSString *)username completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *, NSError *))completion;
```

It sounds like you're using NSURLConnection delegate pattern here, so I will assume that.  Please realize that NSURLConnection also provides a nice [one-shot block method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a) to do the request.

```
// LoginService.m

@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^completion)(NSDictionary *, NSError *);


- (void)login:(NSString *)username completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *, NSError *))completion {

    // copy the block when the request begins
    self.completion = completion;

    // start your request, as you have it now
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSDictionary *dictionary = // parse the data you collected into a dictionary

    // invoke the block with the result
    self.completion(dictionary, nil);
    self.completion = nil;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    self.completion(nil, error);
    self.completion = nil;
}
```

It's polite to dispose of the block (set it to nil) after you invoke it, so it doesn't retain any part of the calling context.